# Loading jquery UI css file on a server

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I've installed a jQuery UI accordion on a Joomla page. Using Chrome development tools I can style it but these settings are lost on page reset. Checking out the css file shows it a CDN - https//ajax/googleapis.com/.....   I want the jQuery UI css file to be on the server so that styling changes are preserved. How can this be done? TIA

Comment: You can create your custom css file, and add it to the page through a `link` attribute. Ensure that the custom css is added after jquer-ui css.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the link of css file http://ajaxapis....
2. Then copy **all inside there** to new file and save it on your server.
3. Edit the css there.
4. Replace the source by the file you have saved, with link attribute. Just replace the **href=...**

Comment: As I mentioned the accordion is being used on Joomla page. How would I get the jquery css file to be referenced.

Comment: isn't joomla provide the ui to set our style manually. Use it